# jQuery copy text into my clipboard from text of texarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea and I want When I move over text area it will show button and when I click this button it will copy text of text area into my clipboard. Just like [mediafire.com](http://mediafire.com). So, what can i do that. I tried to find some solution but it not helpful for me. 
Thank.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <textarea id="myid">My text here</textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you try and what you get ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it's a flash based with some javascript solution like this one :

https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

My guess is that you can't access hardware like keyboard with javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Started the search here and found http://www.steamdev.com/zclip